# Is there any way to get extend axhspan to the outer edges of the plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

### What I'm trying to do

I am working on a graphic that is has color bands in it to signify the meaning of the data displayed. I used `axhspan` to display color bands.

### The problem

I can't figure out though, how to extend `axhspan` to the edges of the plot, leaving me with hardcoding them. I'd rather automatically extend the `axhspan` by pulling the biggest displayed ytick that the data generates, and forbidding the plot to display this weird padding.

```py
import seaborn as sns
from  matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter

sns.set_theme(style="darkgrid")

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax = sns.lineplot(data=df_cw_have, palette="tab10", linewidth=1, legend=False)
sns.regplot(x=df_cw_have.index, y=df_cw_have['ph.value'], data=df_cw_have, scatter=False, line_kws={'color': 'blue', 'linewidth':0.5})

# color bands
plt.axhspan(10000, need_max, facecolor='#00FF00', alpha=0.2)
plt.axhspan(need_min, need_max, facecolor='#FFFF00', alpha=0.2)
plt.axhspan(0, need_min, facecolor='#F08080', alpha=0.2)

plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(lambda x, _: int(x)))
plt.show()
```

[image]

I mean these bands crossed out with red

[image]

Notice how they will always be there, even if I extend the `axhspan` to higher / lower integer values (now `15000` and `-1000`

```py
import seaborn as sns
from  matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter

sns.set_theme(style="darkgrid")

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax = sns.lineplot(data=df_cw_have, palette="tab10", linewidth=1, legend=False)
sns.regplot(x=df_cw_have.index, y=df_cw_have['ph.value'], data=df_cw_have, scatter=False, line_kws={'color': 'blue', 'linewidth':0.5})

# Notice now 15000 and -1000
plt.axhspan(15000, need_max, facecolor='#00FF00', alpha=0.2)
plt.axhspan(need_min, need_max, facecolor='#FFFF00', alpha=0.2)
plt.axhspan(-1000, need_min, facecolor='#F08080', alpha=0.2)


plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(lambda x, _: int(x)))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what you expect, could you annotate the graph or provide a mockup of the expected output?

Comment: I want the grey bands at the top and bottom to disappear and think this can be achieved by automatically selecting the bounds of the yticks, but I think the grey bands are the result of some sort of padding that is automatically applied. I added an annotated graphic

Comment: I think we can add a limit on the y-axis. `ax.set_ylim(0, df['ph.value'].max())`